# DROP and CREATE versus ALTER

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ddl

**QUESTIONS:**

- Is is better to ALTER an object definition (i.e. function, stored procedure) in a production environment, rather than IF EXISTS (...) DROP (...) CREATE...? Does SQL Server treat the two statements differently? Permissions certainly have to be reapplied after a DROP and CREATE, but not after an ALTER...
- When converting a multi-statement table valued function to an inline table valued function in a production update, the function type will be changing (i.e. xtype of "TF" instead of "IF"). Does this require a DROP and CREATE, or can a change like this be done as an ALTER?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the second question (converting a function from an MSTVF to an ITVF), a DROP and CREATE is necessary due to the change in object type. Otherwise the following error will be observed:

> Msg 2010, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   fn_MyFunction, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0] Cannot
>   perform alter on 'dbo.fn_MyFunction' because it is
>   an incompatible object type.